# How to get from database first representative of every letter from alphabet?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to get the first representative of every letter of alphabet from the database.
Saying "first representative" I mean first word which starts with this letter.

Here is an example:

```
Database: aaa,aa,bbb,d,ddddd,eee,E

Output should be: aaa, bbb, d, eee
```

What's the best solution? I dont want to make sql query with thousands of nested selects :)

Comment: I don't understand the extracting criterion: the longest, the shortest, the first letter, a group of 3 letters?

Comment: i just need representative of every letter in alphabet. SQL below solves the problem

Comment: So, as opposed to what you said in your question: `Output should be : aaa, bbb, d, eee`, the output you want is `a, b, d, e` (first letter)

Comment: yeah well, it doesnt matter becouse you can "select min(substr(name,1,1)), id from albums group by substr(name, 1, 1) order by min(name);"

Comment: I asked, because I wanted to give an answer. No more needed. Next time, try to be more precise.

Comment: its sometimes hard to explain problem, the first representative wasnt first letter but first word which starts with this letter. anyway, thans for your time

Comment: Well, the example didn't match the description. That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `group by` on the first letter:

```
select min(col) 
from databasetable
group by substr(col, 1, 1)
order by min(col);
```